# php mail script form only returning headers

Tags: php, email

I have been having trouble getting my php mail script to work. I am fairly new at this so please stay with me.

My php mail form only seems to be returning the headers of the input fields, not the actual information that is typed in them..

Here is what my code is right now. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <form id="contact_form" class="cf" role="form" name="contact_form" method="post" action="mailscript.php">

    <div id="left_form_container">

      <div class="half_left_cf">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input_name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="input_email" placeholder="Email address">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="input_subject" placeholder="Subject">


      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="right_form_container">

      <div class="half_right_cf">
        <textarea name="message" id="input_message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>



        <div id="submit_container">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="input_submit">
        </div>
          </div>

    </div>



  </form>

<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "mail@website.com";

$body = "From: ".$name."\n E-Mail: ".$email."\n Message:\n" .$message;


if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $nameErr = "Name is required";}
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $nameErr = "Email is required";}
if(empty($_POST['subject'])){
    $nameErr = "Subject is required";} 

if(mail ($to, $subject, $body)){

    echo "<script>
            alert('Thank you for sending your message!');
            window.location.href='index.php'; </script";} 

else {
    echo "Mail was not sent!";}
?>
```

As I said, for some reason it just doesn't return any input from the boxes, only the headers..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it returns the headers"_? What headers? What actually happens when you run this script? Have you tried `var_dump($_POST)` to see what it contains? Also, please share the code for the actual form as well.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What is the point of checking that fields contain data, setting an error message when they dont, **and then ignoring it completely**

Comment: You are going to have to show us the FORM as well

Comment: sorry, I've attached the html form as well. What I mean by returns the headers, is that it does send an email, but it only sends: "From: Email: Message:"...